# Skype video not working on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: skype

Can't get video to work in Skype!  When I go into my Video Options to test video I get a black screen.  I know that there is an LD_PRELOAD thing that I have to add, but for some reason it never works on 64 bit!  Am I doing something wrong?

It used to work on 32 bit.

Comment: Sorry - working now!  Finally found what I was looking for!

Comment: Do you mind sharing your knowledge in a self-answer to this question? Some of us will appreciate it a lot. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here's what I did to fix the problem:

I edited the skype.desktop file so the command to run contained the following:

`bash -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skype %U'`

Didn't need to reboot, just opened skype from the .desktop file and it works!

Answer (score 1):

You should do this:

Install the libv4l 32bit version (even if you are using 64bit)

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0:i386
```

Locate the the path for the installed library (if there are two, chose the 32bit one - i386, ex: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so)

```
locate v4l1compat.so
```

Use the indicated path in running your command (without quotes)

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skype
```